# dynamic sitemap : xml or html

Tags: html, xml, sitemap

I've created website with dynamic content, and I want google to know all my pages, so I've given a file "mysitemap.xml" via webmaster tools.

Basically, my links are like mysite.com/one-id/one-name , with one-id an id between 1 and 2000 (but will be greater with the time...).

I'm wondering if I need to create a page on my website (a kind of html sitemap), which will list all these links to help google bots to find my web pages, or is it enough for google to have the xml sitemap?

The problem is that the html sitemap will be very ugly and only a "for google" page, so I want to avoid this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Google only requires a sitemap.

Comment: yes but I don't know how much it will impact to put links on my pages. for exemple, in stackoverflow, at the left of the page, there is a pane "related" which contains links, I think it is mostly for google bots ?

Answer (score 0):

Sitemap is for Search Engines and Navigation is for humans.
Sitemap includes page's content type, update frequency, last modified, etc.
Navigation may include dropdown menus, hyperlinks, etc.